# What is the relationship between Hecke algebras and the enveloping algebra of Lie groups?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Here is the story as I see it.

Let $G$ be an abelian locally compact group. Then the (spherical) Hecke algebra for $K=1$ is by definition the endomorphism algebra of $l^2(G)$ as a $G$-module, where the $G$ action on $l^2(G)$ is defined by taking $f(x)$ to $f(x-g)$. In turn, this Hecke algebra can be identified with $l^1(G)$ (by $\rho\in l^1(G)$ mapping to the $G$-invariant endomorphism $f(x)\mapsto\int_G \rho(s)f(x+s)$), where composition in $End_G(l^2(G))$ becomes convolution in $l^1(G)$.

I'm trying to connect the above story with the following story. If $G$ is real Lie group, then the enveloping algebra of its Lie algebra can be identified with left-invariant differential operators.

I think I'm missing out on the big story here... Somehow simultaneously diagonalizing the center of $End_G(l^2(G))$ or the center of the enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra of $G$ (are they one and the same?!) is related to the irreducible representations of $G$? I'm pretty confused about how all this ties together.

So here are a few concrete questions:

1. How is $End_G(l^2(G))$ related to the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra of $G$? Are they isomorphic? (The center of the universal enveloping algebra can be identified with left $G$-invariant differential operators; differential operators are a *kind* of function from $l^2(G)$ to itself, but it also operates on functions that are not in $l^2(G)$, and it is certainly not *all* the functions from $l^2(G)$ to itself... So the relationship here isn't quite clear to me...)
2. It looks to me like if instead of $l^2(G)$ we looked at the space of *all* functions $G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, then the center of $End_G(\mathbb{C}^G)$ would exactly be the functions that are homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. But I also feel like this is the wrong way to think about this... So my concrete question here is: In the classical Fourier Analysis situation example specifically, how do the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian fit into the two stories above? I feel like the Laplacian, being a differential operator, belongs to the story about the center of the universal enveloping algebra; but I also see it sometimes in the context of an endomorphism of $l^2(G)$...
3. Given my level of understanding, what facts do you think would help elucidate to me how all the pieces fit together? Do you think I have any misconceptions?

Comment: I think "automorphism group" should be "endomorphism algebra" in your description of the spherical Hecke algebra for $K=1$.  Automorphisms are the invertible endomorphisms.

Comment: "abelian td-group": do you mean "totally disconnected locally compact abelian group"? If so, why "abelian td-group or abelian lc-group" since one encompasses the other?

Comment: "the Hecke algebra is by definition $Aut_G(\ell^2(G))$: this sounds weird, this is not an algebra. Don't you mean $End_G(\ell^2(G))$ instead?

Comment: Edited appropriately, thanks!